ACS physical chemistry question about internal energy
$$\ce{A(s) + 2B(g)->2C(s) + D(g)}$$
$\text{d}U$ at standard state conditions is measured at a temperature $T$ in a constant volume calorimeter.  $\text{d}H$ at standard conditions is approximately:
A.) $\text{d}U-RT$
B.) $\text{d}U$
C.) $\text{d}U+RT$
D.) $\text{d}U+2RT$
My first instinct was $\text{d}H=\text{d}U$.  The book claims the answer is $\text{d}U-RT$. In my head I'm thinking:
$\text{d}H=\text{d}U+\text{d}(PV)$ and if the gas involved is ideal we have: $\text{d}H=\text{d}U+\text{d}(nRT)=\text{d}U+RT\text{d}n+nR\text{d}T$.
$\text{d}T=0$ and $\text{d}n=-1$ so $\text{d}H=\text{d}U-RT$.
Is this the correct thinking? I suppose I don't understand why I'm allowed to invoke the ideal gas law in this situation, especially since the reaction also involves solid and I'm not told the gas is ideal.
I would think it would be more correct to say that $\text{d}H=\text{d}U+\text{d}(PV)=\text{d}U+V\text{d}P+P\text{d}V$ and conclude that $\text{d}V=0$.  So $\text{d}H=\text{d}U+V\text{d}P$ but this isn't an answer.

Sometimes, the right and the expected answer match each other, and other times they do not. The latter usually happens if the task author considers a higher level of simplification than a student solving it.

Chem+Math MathJax formatting:
Basics / Expressions/formulas/equations / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

When I would solve this question I'd first see the phrasing "approximately" which guides me towards an ideal gas law situation as first approximation. So I would do the same as you:
$$H = U + pV \longrightarrow dH = dU + pdV + Vdp$$
where due to the constant volume of the experiment the second term on the right hand side of the second equation vanishes. The only thing that we need to figure out is the pressure change due to this reaction. Looking at the reaction equation we indeed can conclude that the pressure will decrease during the reaction due to the stoichiomety of the gassious reactants and products. To estimate this pressure change we invoke the ideal gas law
$$pV = nRT \longrightarrow dp = dn R T/V + nRdT/V-nRTdV/V^2$$
where the isochoric conditions lead to $dV = 0$ and because we want to estimate the pressure change at a certain temperature I would say $dT = 0$. This gives
$$dp = dn RT/V .$$ Lastly, I would agree with your analysis that $dn=-1$ as "per molecule D generated in the reaction you loose 2 gassious molecules B hence a nett decrease of gassious particles" such that you finally arrive at
$$dH = dU-RT.$$
So I think what you did was already correct and you would use the ideal gas law in this exercise because you want to approximate the enthalpy change. The solid reactants and products will of course not change the pressure in the experiment and  we care only about the gassious species in the problem to determine $dn$

Note that as the typographic rule of thumb, the only things in italic are one-letter variables and physical constants.
